# Search for element list inside list in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, nested-lists

My objective is to search for the word after "IDENTIFIER" in the list. I have input as list which can have list inside list inside list or just list inside list. Basically we have to find how many list inside lists are present and then perform the check.

I have lists inside lists as shown below

```
      [['CLASS', 'class'], ['CLASS', 'animal'], ['LCURLY', '{'], [[['INT', 'int'], ['IDENTIFIER', 'a'], ['SEMICOLON', ';']], [['BOOL', 'bool'], ['IDENTIFIER', 'x'], ['SEMICOLON', ';']]], ['RCURLY', '}']]
```

I want to search for next element after the word IDENTIFIER. that is i am looking for "a" , and "x".  This is case of list inside list inside list. That is two groups of nested list.

But I also have a list as follows:

```
         [['INT', 'int'], ['IDENTIFIER', 'e'], ['SEMICOLON', ';']]
```

This is case of only list inside list. Now i want to search for word after IDENTIFIER that is "e".

So, Basically all I want to know how to search if there is list inside list and if there is no list inside list then perform a check. All I could think is write a function where i would pass my list and then check if there exist a list inside the list if there is still list then call the function again ( recursively ) and once there is no such list present then perform the check.

Is this the right way to go ahead ? Are there any better suggestions than this .

Comment: look at `itertools` - especially `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: Ya, basically I would go with calling the a function recursively and check if list exist  and so on ...